# How to prevent object change after function executes?

Tags: javascript, sorting, object, closures

I have googled a lot but cannot get it...

I have an object

```
var games = [
  {name: 'Pako', rating: 4.21},
  {name: 'Hill Climb Racing', rating: 3.88},
  {name: 'Angry Birds Space', rating: 3.88},
  {name: 'Badland', rating: 4.33}
];
```

And function which takes this object as an argument (obj_array). It is basically doing just sorting of that array and returns a sorted array, just as written in many tutorials.

```
function sortByAttribute(obj_array, attr) {
...

return obj_array.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
    if (obj1[prop[0]] == obj2[prop[0]]) {
        return (obj1[prop[1]] < obj2[prop[1]] ? 1: -1)*sortOrder;
    }
    return ((obj1[prop[0]] > obj2[prop[0]]) ? 1 : -1) * sortOrder;
});
```

}

So, then I have the following lines:

```
console.log(sortByAttribute(games, 'name'));

console.log(games);

console.log(sortByAttribute(games, ['-rating', 'name']));
```

All of them produce the same result and show the result of the last sorting. I understand, that most probably the answer is in the scope and closures, but I cannot get how I can change the code so that it shows all three outputs differently.

PS. All this code is now located in the same file.

Comment: i don't see where `attr` is being used?

Comment: make a copy of the object.

Comment: **attr** is  **prop** ? From how you use it, looks like the filters...

Comment: yes, prop is made from the attr. what is the proper way of doing a copy?  I tried with doing var arr = games; in the beginning of the function, but it did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stringify and parse it and use the copy:

```
var gamesCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(games));
```

Comment: is it a common way to do it? I tried with doing var arr = games; in the beginning of the function, but it did not work.

Comment: `var arr = games` keeps the reference to `games`, so it does not help. usualy a deep copy would help. the work around with JSON is common way to archive that. the only drawbackl is, it works only with properties.